# Como sair do loop VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Oi pessoal vcs podem me ajudar, eu estou rodando dois loops, porém preciso para de rodar o loop quando a variável rows2 for igual a 38. Sou iniciante em programação. Não sei como resolve.

```
Sub qty()
    
    rows1 = 2
    rows2 = 28
    
    contador = 0
    
    While linhas2 < 38
        
        While Sheets("teste").Cells(rows1, 2) <> ""
        
        
            If Sheets("teste").Cells(rows2, 1) = Sheets("teste").Cells(Rows, 1) Then
            
                Sheets("teste").Cells(rows1, 4) = Sheets("teste").Cells(Rows, 4) + Sheets("teste").Cells(rows2, 4)
                rows2 = rows2 + 1
                rows1 = rows1 + 1
                
            Else
                
                rows2 = rows2 + 1
            
            
            End If
        
        Wend
    
        
    Wend
    

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso apenas adicionando uma variável `continuar` em seguida utilizando-a como critério para o `While` e atualizando o valor da variável a cada loop.

Para entender melhor, confira abaixo todos os lugares onde eu incluí essa variável `continuar`.

```vb
Sub qty()

    rows1 = 2
    rows2 = 28
    
    contador = 0
    continuar = True
    
    While linhas2 < 38 And continuar
        
        While Sheets("teste").Cells(rows1, 2) <> "" And continuar
        
            If Sheets("teste").Cells(rows2, 1) = Sheets("teste").Cells(Rows, 1) Then
            
                Sheets("teste").Cells(rows1, 4) = Sheets("teste").Cells(Rows, 4) + Sheets("teste").Cells(rows2, 4)
                rows2 = rows2 + 1
                rows1 = rows1 + 1
                
            Else
                
                rows2 = rows2 + 1
            
            
            End If
            
            continuar = rows2 < 38
            
        Wend
        
    Wend
    

End Sub
```

Comment: opa, vlw parceiro. Muito obrigado!
Me ajudou bastante!!

Comment: Legal! Tendo essa resposta te ajudado a resolver o problema, marque-a como aceita para fechar a questão. Abs